# JSP - Continue only if this id exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am very new to JSP. I have following code.

```
         var code = $('#codeForm').find('#disCode');
         var disCodeVal = disCode.val().trim();
```

The #discode is an input field which is either defined or not based on some condition. How can i add an if condition to test if #discode is defined and only if it is defined then proceed to getting disCodeVal?

EDIT: Based on a condition when the page loads it will either have an input field called disCode or not.

```
  <c:if test="${url eq 'test'}">                                     
         <a:fixedGridColumn position="${'last'}" fixedColumn="${'left'}" >
              <a:textInput id="disCode" name="code" value="${disCode}" required="true" />
        </a:fixedGridColumn>
  </c:if>
```

Then when submit button is clicked a function is attached to it as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 P.when("jQuery").execute(function($) {

     $("#submitBtn").click( function(e) { 
            var code = $('#codeForm').find('#disCode');
            var disCodeVal = disCode.val().trim();
            ..// more validation code for other input fields which are always present
```

Now i want to only activate the above two lines on the click of the button if disCode input field exists.

Comment: This appears to be JavaScript only.  Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do?

Comment: I added more details to above question

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are having JQuery code in your JSP. It is simple. If the element doesn't exist (not defined), the JQuery selector will give you 0 as its length.

Do it like following:

```
if($('#disCode').length > 0) {
   ...
}
```